# Best choice for 2.5" hard drive upgrade for a dell inspiron 1501 laptop?

Tags: laptop, hard-drive

Right now it's 80Gb 5400rpm sata150 what could be the best upgrade ???

320 Gb+ 7200rpm sata 300 (but used at 150 ???) but what about power usage (even used without the battery all the time) ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WD Scorpio Blue](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136314&cm_re=scorpio_blue-_-22-136-314-_-Product) seems to be a popular choice now. Not only is it super quiet, but it's a great deal for 500GB, and an excellent performer. Of course [an SSD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820167024&cm_re=x-25m-_-20-167-024-_-Product) would be ideal, but keeping price in mind, I'd say a scorpio blue is the best choice right now.

Keep in mind, the X-25M is a solid state drive:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got a 160 GB Scorpio Blue a couple months ago for my 1501. It's nice. That + 2 GB Crucial RAM have rather revived my notebook (meaning a very nice speed and storage boost). I was outgrowing it...